# Expression of type EmptyNode.type does not conform to expected type SortedList[T]

Tags: scala

I have a very simple type declaration that I thought would work but it doesn't, any ideas on what's wrong here:

```
object SortedList {

  def apply[T]() : SortedList[T] = EmptyNode

}

trait SortedList[T <: Ordered]

private case class Node[T](value : T, next : SortedList[T]) extends SortedList[T]
private object EmptyNode extends SortedList[Nothing]
```

I'm pretty sure `EmptyNode` here is a `SortedList[T]` for any `T`.

Comment: Your `SortedList` is not covariant. Try `trait SortedList[+T <: Ordered]`.

Comment: Can you include this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare the trait's parameter as covariant:

```
trait SortedList[+T]
```

This way the `EmptyNode` will be a subtype of all other `SortedList`s.

It turned out my code was wrong (I have not tested). Thanks @som-snytt for pointing out the problems. The way the original question was asked it is not possible in my opinion. Here is the closest I could get:

```
object SortedList {
  def apply[T]() : SortedList[T] = EmptyNode
}

class SortedList[+T: Ordering]{
}

private case class Node[T:Ordering](value : T, next : SortedList[T]) extends SortedList[T]
implicit val nothingOrdering = new Ordering[Nothing] {
  def compare(x: Nothing, y: Nothing) = 0
}
private object EmptyNode extends SortedList[Nothing]
```

Unfortunately this makes the following also compile:

```
val s: SortedList[Thread] = SortedList()
```

Probably a different -not `Nothing`- lower bound would be a solution, but probably a parametrized `apply` is unavoidable.

Comment: `EmptyNode` is a subtype, not supertype. But there are other problems: `Ordered` takes a type param, and you can't say `trait SortedList[+A <: Ordered[A]]`. The standard `SortedMap`, for instance, just has a member to define an `Ordering[A]`.

Comment: @som-snytt You are right, thanks for the correction. In case you plan to provide a better answer I'll delete mine. (Probably tomorrow I'll try an update.)

Comment: You're right about `+`, and that's all you need for a green check. :)